# Nignx rewrite pattern on search query?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

Its a very basic thing i need to do, but i cant figure this one out.

i have following rule in my nginx.conf

```
    location ^/search {
        #try_files index.php?search=$1  last;
        rewrite ^/search/(.*)/ index.php?search=$1;
        #rewrite ^/search/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?search=$1&page=$2;
    }

    location ^/article {
        rewrite ^/article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?layout=article&id=$1;
    }

    location ^/images {
        rewrite ^/images/([^/]+)$ /images/$1 break;
        rewrite ^/images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /images/$1/$2 break;
    }

    location ^/css {
        rewrite ^/css/([^/]+)$ /css/$1 break;
        rewrite ^/css/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /css/$1/$2 break;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

basically all i want to do is 
match below query on search to this above.

```
example.com/search-term1/
or
example.com/search term/
or 
example.com/search/search-term1/
or
example.com/search/search-term1/page/1/
```

above url patterns ?how do i do this ? above rule gives me error 500 Internal server error.

in the Nginx log i get following as

```
2015/08/05 12:56:39 [error] 11136#0: *2 could not find named location "@rewrite", client: 202.172.107.194, server: example.com, request: "GET /search/search-term1/page/1/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: Show full config. Also you either add `~` flag or remove `^` in `location` directive.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue by moving them out of the location block and putting them directly into the server block.